# Trying to Convert a cucumber DataTable as a string of array/list in Typescript

Tags: typescript, cucumber

I want to utilise the data table in cucumber as list in Typescript

```css
When user select these
    |Steps| 
    |a| 
    |b|
    |c|
```

I want the steps to be utilised something like
const steps = dataTable.asLists(String.class)

If question already answered, please share pointers
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have achieved list/array in typescript from the cucumber datatable

```js
var steps = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dataTable.rows().length; i++) {
      steps.push(dataTable.rows()[i][0]);
    }
```